# ++ operator for a BST Class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++builder

I have already created a BST class, with a root node, and left and right node. It is working perfectly. I am trying to create a ++ operator Iterator, which can just go through each node and increment its. This is what I get so far, I am still thinking it gets something to do with my constructor. Below is just the nested Iterator class that I included in the BST class. I just `cout` to see if it is working but it keeps printing out 0.

```
class Iterator
{
private:
    // private iterator state...
    nodeptr root;
public:
    Iterator(nodeptr roots_) : root(roots_) {};
    ~Iterator() {}
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) const { return (this-> root != rhs.root); }
    bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs) const {
        return (this->root == rhs.root);
    }

    Iterator operator++(T) {
      nodeptr ptr = root;
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            cout << "The tree is empty" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ptr->left != NULL)
            {
                ptr = ptr->left;
            }
            cout << ptr->data << " ";
            if (ptr->right != NULL)
            {
                ptr = ptr->right;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "_";
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a iterator should do in a BST class, anyway...

(1) I don't know what is a `operator++ (T)`; as far I know, as method of a class, `operator++` can be with signature `operator++()` (pre-increment) or `operator++(int)` (post-increment); I suppose you're trying to define a post-increment operator (because you add a dummy argument and because you returning a copy of `Iterator`, not a reference) but the dummy argument should be of type `int`, not of type `T`

(2) pre-increment or post-increment, the `operator++()` should modify the object; your operator doesn't modify it: it create a local copy of the lonely member (`root`) and modify the local copy; sequential calls to your `operator++(T)` should give the same effect because are doing the same thing; I suppose your intention was to modify the member `root`, instead of the local variable `ptr`

(3) supposing (presence of the dummy argument and no reference in return type) your intention was the make a post-increment operator, you have to create a **copy** of the object, modify the object and **return** **the** **copy**; you're (not) modifying the object and returning the object itself (`return *this;`) and this is the typical behavior (adding some change in object and return by reference) of a pre-increment operator.

To make it simple, I suppose you should write something as

```
//       v <--- observe the return by reference
Iterator & operator++ ()
 {
   // something that modify the Iterator object 

   // return the object itself as reference
   return *this;
 }


// no reference here: return a copy
Iterator operator++ (int)
 {
   // copy of the object **before** the increment
   // (but you have also to develop a copy constructor)
   Iterator copy { *this };

   // pre-increment of the object
   ++(*this);

   // return of the before the increment copy
   return copy;
 }
```